# CSS - Responsive Background Images inside a div

Tags: css

Take the following code:-

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="nottingham-park">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#nottingham-park {
    background: url(http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/nottingham-park.png);
    background-size:100% auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    //height: 700px;
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mfyuf1yb/1/)

If I don't set a height to `#nottingham-park`, the background image isn't visible, if I set a height, it's not responsive.

How can I display the image so it's always 100% width and auto height?

Comment: usually you should just add content to nottingham-park, so that it extends naturally. What height would you expect CSS to choose?

Comment: You won't get a responsive design. Your image will always have `100%` width and whatever fixed height that represents. Maybe you are looking for `background-size: cover`?

Comment: @IceFire - there is no content inside the div, so is the only option to not use background images and use just an <img>?

Comment: cover will still not display the image @somethinghere

Comment: I mean, why not apply the background-image to the object that really has your page's content? Or do you not want to have any content at all?

Comment: If your box has no height, indeed, there will be nothing displayed. Buty if you set a height, your image doesn't resize because of the `100%` bit. Although setting a height and cover should solve your issue.

Comment: Alternatively, you could have the height be responsive based on Screen height? See `vh` http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can force the size of #nottingham-park to the size of the background-image with padding-top. see the comments in the css to see how you can calculate what the padding-top should be.

this way your image will be responsive and never stretched out of proportion.

hope this is what you are asking for.

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#nottingham-park {
    background: url(http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/nottingham-park.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
  
    /* 
    width of image / height of image * width
    699px / 1200px * 100  = 57.7208918249
    (change the 100 in this formula to whatever you want.)
  */
    padding-top: 57.7208918249%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="nottingham-park">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

How about a fluid `padding-bottom` ?

[Like this](https://jsfiddle.net/mfyuf1yb/6/)

```
#nottingham-park {
    background: url(http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/nottingham-park.png);
    background-size:100% auto;
    background-repeat: n-repeat;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom : 55%;
}
```

Comment: The problem with that is that if you have content beneath, you then have to use several media queries to change the min height, look here https://jsfiddle.net/mfyuf1yb/3/

Comment: You're right, I propose an other solution with a fluid padding

Comment: Also, did you mean `no-repeat` and this padding won't work as the padding (in %) is based on the height of the box, which as far as we know has no contents. If you change it to `vh` it might work.

Comment: It didn't work in my example with `vh` units. You're right on the fact that I didn't care about the `repeat` of the background with this solution. It depends whats @nsilva really wants.